# correct way to create a pivot table in postgresql using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, case-when

I am trying to create a pivot table type view in postgresql and am nearly there!  Here is the basic query:

```
select 
acc2tax_node.acc, tax_node.name, tax_node.rank 
from 
tax_node, acc2tax_node 
where 
tax_node.taxid=acc2tax_node.taxid and acc2tax_node.acc='AJ012531';
```

And the data:

```
   acc    |          name           |     rank     
----------+-------------------------+--------------
 AJ012531 | Paromalostomum fusculum | species
 AJ012531 | Paromalostomum          | genus
 AJ012531 | Macrostomidae           | family
 AJ012531 | Macrostomida            | order
 AJ012531 | Macrostomorpha          | no rank
 AJ012531 | Turbellaria             | class
 AJ012531 | Platyhelminthes         | phylum
 AJ012531 | Acoelomata              | no rank
 AJ012531 | Bilateria               | no rank
 AJ012531 | Eumetazoa               | no rank
 AJ012531 | Metazoa                 | kingdom
 AJ012531 | Fungi/Metazoa group     | no rank
 AJ012531 | Eukaryota               | superkingdom
 AJ012531 | cellular organisms      | no rank
```

What I am trying to get is the following:

```
acc      | species                  | phylum
AJ012531 | Paromalostomum fusculum  | Platyhelminthes
```

I am trying to do this with CASE WHEN, so I've got as far as the following:

```
select 
acc2tax_node.acc, 
CASE tax_node.rank WHEN 'species' THEN tax_node.name ELSE NULL END as species, 
CASE tax_node.rank WHEN 'phylum' THEN tax_node.name ELSE NULL END as phylum 
from 
tax_node, acc2tax_node 
where 
tax_node.taxid=acc2tax_node.taxid and acc2tax_node.acc='AJ012531';
```

Which gives me the output:

```
   acc    |         species         |     phylum      
----------+-------------------------+-----------------
 AJ012531 | Paromalostomum fusculum | 
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         | Platyhelminthes
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         | 
 AJ012531 |                         |
```

Now I know that I have to group by acc at some point, so I try

```
select 
acc2tax_node.acc, 
CASE tax_node.rank WHEN 'species' THEN tax_node.name ELSE NULL END as sp, 
CASE tax_node.rank WHEN 'phylum' THEN tax_node.name ELSE NULL END as ph 
from 
tax_node, acc2tax_node 
where 
tax_node.taxid=acc2tax_node.taxid and acc2tax_node.acc='AJ012531' 
group by acc2tax_node.acc;
```

But I get the dreaded

```
ERROR:  column "tax_node.rank" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

All the previous examples I've been able to find use something like SUM() around the CASE statements, so I guess that is the aggregate function.  I have tried using FIRST():

```
select 
acc2tax_node.acc, 
FIRST(CASE tax_node.rank WHEN 'species' THEN tax_node.name ELSE NULL END) as sp, 
FIRST(CASE tax_node.rank WHEN 'phylum' THEN tax_node.name ELSE NULL END) as ph 
from tax_node, acc2tax_node where tax_node.taxid=acc2tax_node.taxid and acc2tax_node.acc='AJ012531' group by acc2tax_node.acc;
```

but get the error:

```
ERROR:  function first(character varying) does not exist
```

Can anyone offer any hints?

Comment: Could you please post the results of this query: `SELECT * FROM acc2tax_node WHERE acc = 'AJ012531'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use MAX() or MIN(), not FIRST().  In this scenario, you will have all NULLs in the column per each group value except for, at most, one with a not null value.  By definition, this is both the MIN and the MAX of that set of values (all nulls are excluded).

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you.  For some reason I assumed that MAX() would not work because I was using string values.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL does have a couple of functions for pivot queries, see this article at [Postgresonline](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/14-CrossTab-Queries-in-PostgreSQL-using-tablefunc-contrib.html). You can find these functions in the [contrib](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/tablefunc.html).

Comment: Yes, I suspect that the correct way to do this is with scrosstab. I'd still like to figure out what I'm doing wrong here for my own education.

Answer (score 1):

As Matthew Wood pointed out, use MIN() or MAX(), not FIRST():

```
SELECT 
    an.acc, 
    MAX(
        CASE tn.rank 
            WHEN 'species' THEN tn.name 
            ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) AS species, 
    MAX(
        CASE tn.rank 
            WHEN 'phylum' THEN tn.name 
            ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) AS phylum 
FROM tax_node tn, 
    acc2tax_node an
WHERE tn.taxid = an.taxid 
    and an.acc = 'AJ012531' 
GROUP by an.acc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  atn.acc, ts.name AS species, tp.name AS phylum
FROM    acc2tax_node atn
LEFT JOIN
        tax_node ts
ON      ts.taxid = atn.taxid
        AND ts.rank = 'species'
LEFT JOIN
        tax_node tp
ON      tp.taxid = atn.taxid
        AND tp.rank = 'phylum'
WHERE   atn.acc = 'AJ012531 '
```

Answer (score 0):

Further info as requested (in a reply rather than a comment for nice formatting):

```
SELECT * FROM acc2tax_node WHERE acc = 'AJ012531';

   acc    | taxid  
----------+--------
 AJ012531 |  66400
 AJ012531 |  66399
 AJ012531 |  39216
 AJ012531 |  39215
 AJ012531 | 166235
 AJ012531 | 166384
 AJ012531 |   6157
 AJ012531 |  33214
 AJ012531 |  33213
 AJ012531 |   6072
 AJ012531 |  33208
 AJ012531 |  33154
 AJ012531 |   2759
 AJ012531 | 131567
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute:

```
SELECT report.* FROM crosstab(
 select 
 acc2tax_node.acc, tax_node.name, tax_node.rank 
 from 
 tax_node, acc2tax_node 
 where 
 tax_node.taxid=acc2tax_node.taxid and acc2tax_node.acc='AJ012531';
) AS report(species text, enus text, family text, ...)
```