# Query results showing rows as columns

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

I have a form that dynamically creates checkboxes. The user signs in and selects 0 to all the checkboxes. The checkbox array is generated from the table 'options'. The form submit records into 2 tables 'survey' (one record of person data) and 'selections' (the survey key and the options key (or keys)).
I want to pull out a report that will show all of the possible options as column headings with a list of people from the survey table who selected that option. So my result would look like this:

```
    FirstAid   Triage    Firefighting  HamRadio
    Sam         Sue        Sam
    Judy        Judy       Bill
                Bob
```

So all of the options show on the results, even if no one has selected it.

Structure of the tables are:

```
     OPTIONS
     option_id   description

     SURVEY
     survey_id   name

     SELECTED OPTIONS
     survey_id   option_id
```

This is a simplified example of the actual data, but includes the critical pieces (I think). How can I use SQL to get the results I need?

Thanks

Comment: The method of performing a pivot/crosstab query varies depending on the type of database. Please indicate if you are using Oracle, MySql, Sql-Server, etc.

Comment: It's postgres 8.1. The form is PHP, I'm using PDO to query the database and sending the result out to Excel using the Pear Excel Writer.  Thaks--

Comment: But, any method will do. I'm primarily looking for the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have not used Postgres in several years so there may be better methods of accomplishing this task than the ones that I list.

**Option 1:** Use `Case` `When` statements as was done in the below linked solution.
[correct way to create a pivot table in postgresql using CASE WHEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477231/correct-way-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-postgresql-using-case-when)

**Option 2:** Use the `Crosstab` function available in the `tablefunc contrib` as was done in the below linked solution.
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)
Documentation for `crosstab tablefunc contrib` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: Thank you. I'd already read through a couple of those but had trouble applying them to my situation. Thanks for the pointers though.