# SQL values for repeating person moved in next column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write an sql query to accomplish the following operation:

| Client_ID | Payment | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10$ | 01/01/2020 |
| 2 | 5$ | 01/01/2020 |
| 2 | 12$ | 02/01/2020 |
| 2 | 6$ | 04/01/2020 |
| 3 | 11$ | 02/01/2020 |
| 3 | 15$ | 05/01/2020 |

The table must be formatted so each client_id appears only once, and each payment made by the client must have a separate column for 1st, 2nd, 3rd payment ect..

| Client_ID | Payment 1 | Payment 2 | Payment 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10$ | 0$ | 0$ |
| 2 | 5$ | 12$ | 6$ |
| 3 | 11$ | 15$ | 0$ |

Please help.

Comment: You're looking for something called a "Pivot/crosstab"  which can be handled manually though case expressions.  If it's a dynamic pivot meaning you have a dynamic number of possible payments per client then this gets into dynamic SQL and is likely better handled though the user interface.  So do you always have just 3 payments or could it be 1, 3, 5 or any number?  Example of Dynamic though not recommended in a DB as it uses dynamic SQL which is usually sub optimal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087948/dynamic-pivot-query-using-postgresql-9-3

Comment: Additional examples using an extension: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905  and using case expression which isn't dynamic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477231/correct-way-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-postgresql-using-case-when

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.

Comment: The number of payments can vary, I just used 3 for the example. My idea is to use the maximum number of payments done by a client in order to determine the number of columns to be added.

Comment: Why do you want the database to do this? Handling a varying number of columns is more a problem for the front end; there being a fixed number of columns and variable number of rows is generally a fairly core principle of database use/SQL. Sure, you can get around it, but it's awkward to do and makes the results typically mroe difficult to work with

Comment: @CaiusJard it is just a task I am trying to learn how to do. No particular reason.

Comment: Oof.. If there's no particular reason for doing a dynamic crosstab I wouldn't bother. I've no qualms about teaching you a fixed one though

Comment: Yes, I do not feel that applying this dynamic crosstab is necessary. A static one would do just fine as the number of payments per client is not expected to exceed 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While what you ask can be accomplished you will find it is not worth the effort as pivoting requires advanced knowledge of the results, well at least the exact size. Since you have varying number of payments you will need to dynamically create the query. Meaning you write a code which looks at the data then writes the query before executing it. That can get very complex very quickly and the result is a maintenance nightmare. Let me propose the following instead.

Your idea to *maximum number of payments done by a client in order to determine the number of columns* has merit, but let SQL do that work (which it does easily), then let your client's presentation manager handle the pivoting. The following builds one row per customer with an array of payments for each customer and adding columns for number of payments for that customer and the maximum number of payments for any customer. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e94890eaa8ebfb82d6d4561932721b50)).

```
select client_id, payments_made
     , array_length(payments_made,1) num_payments
     , max(array_length(payments_made,1)) over() max_payments
  from (     
         select client_id, array_agg(payment order by paid_date)  payments_made
           from payments 
          group by client_id
       ) gs;
```

Comment: I guess, if you consider listing all 45 possibilities in  the query simpler. IMHO it is not.  Is there a **business rule** stating  no be more that 45 payments per client.  Otherwise you are just making a arbitrary decision not supported by requirements.  How about the client that for reasons on there end makes 2 regular payments instead of just 1. Do you now face the possibility of 90 payments during a given period.? As my mentor told me many many years ago: *As a developer your job is the systematic control of miracles*. In other words properly handle those events that can(not) happen.

Comment: Thanks for the help, your code with the arrays seems to have accomplished what I was trying to achieve in a much simpler way :).

Comment: Glade to help. If the answer solved your issue please accept it. This helps future questioners with the same/similar issue and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Kindly do not leave successfully answered question in the unanswered queue.